# CakePHP 3 - Inner Join

Tags: php, cakephp

Como faço um inner join para relacionar uma tabela de artigos com uma tabela de artigos favoritos usando o cakephp 3.

tabela de favoritos:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `favorites` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `favorited` datetime NOT NULL
)
```

tabela de artigos:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: cakephp não é banco de dados é um framework PHP, acredito que na verdade a sua duvida seja sobre mysql, estou certo?

Comment: Na vdd é sobre as Associações do CakePHP >> http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html
Porém quando tento fazer a utilização ele me retorna todos os dados da tabela de artigos quando na vdd deveria me retornar apenas os artigos associados a tabela de favoritos

Comment: Suas tabelas são em innoDB (ou semelhante)? Usam chave estrangeira? Poste a estrutura real de ambas tabelas (incluindo as chaves estrangeiras se tiver e se for `n:m` a tabela que fica no meio das duas... SE FOR N:M), acredito que é possivel sim fazer. :) Aguardo

Comment: o foreing key seria feito pela id da tabela articles e na tabela favorites pela coluna 'article_id', seria uma associação n:n. pois a cada artigo favorito é uma linha na tabela favorites

Comment: Você ainda não tem as tabelas é isto?

Comment: eu tenho, porém o problema está no código do cake onde não consigo 'cruzar' essas tabelas

Comment: Então poste o que eu pedi no comentário, todas tabelas que irão se relacionar, tipo de tabela e quais fields fazem a chave estrangeira na pergunta por favor.

Comment: Atualizei com as informaçõe da 2 tabela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No CakePHP 3.x é desta forma!

Exemplo:

```
$this->Favorites
    ->find('all')
    ->leftJoin('articles', 'articles.id = Favorites.article_id');
```

Documentação:

[leftJoin()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_leftJoin), [rightJoin()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_rightJoin),  [innerJoin()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_innerJoin) e manualmente [join()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_join)